# Rebuilt as another app / Full-featured reputation loader

Tags: app, website

> This version of app is obsolete. <s>I've just started rebuilding it, will be life *approximately today or tomorrow* (Feb 5-6, 2023)</s>. New version is live! Check it there: [Voting activity tracker v2: check your voting activity on per-site meta!](https://stackapps.com/questions/9659/voting-activity-tracker-v2-check-your-voting-activity-on-per-site-meta)

*Original post below*

I've made a reputation loader, the primary purposes of which are:

- track **per-site meta pseudo reputation**
- ability to link to the specific day in the reputation history

The app <s>is located there</s> (link broken, it was a free webhosting which apparently terminated my account a million of years ago).

Gif demo for historic reasons:

> [image]

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I mean that [app] uses api, so tagging it with [script] :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bug:
When you enter a site, we can do `meta.stackexchange`. However, entering `meta.stackexchange.com` breaks **EVERYTHING**! Yes, everything. [image]
Please fix this.

Comment: Huh. I can't get it to work in Firefox at all.  Always returns "There were no net reputation changes on this day".