Voting activity tracker v2: check your voting activity on per-site meta!




About:
In 2015 I built a tool to check your voting activity on meta. It was live probably for a year before my free domain was terminated.
A lot of time passed since then, and a few days ago I decided to fully rebuild this tool, so here it is, in the gorgeous new design, completely new! It has nothing in common with the first version, I couldn't even find its code (though it was still miles behind, the new one actually houses some convenient features and unique design)
App website

Tool is live here: voting activity tool v2.0.

Usage:

select any site from dropdown with convenient autocomplete feature
select a day using date picker
find your ID (it's in /users/{user-id}) and paste it into user ID field

Features:

sleek design that allows a quick, comfortable overview of all your votes during any selected day
expandable votes with a unique "daily net score" feature
no need to input your ID and site every time, the app saves them
"revert" button in the date picker sets the date for today

Screenshot

Technologies
This is a webapp, built standard HTML/CSS/JS (no libs). Also, Cloudflare Worker as a proxy to fetch information from Stack Exchange (wouldn't be possible otherwise due to CORS policy); other than that pretty much nothing.
Bugs? Requests?
Please report / request below in comments / answers
Why tho?...
I realize that this is more of a gimmick, rather than a widely useful tool, but still. Moreover, there was a feature request years ago, so probably someone would benefit from this nowadays.

It was not obvious to me, perhaps you could mention in the text on the app that the user id is different for each site.
Also, why limit it to a day?  A date range would be useful.

hi, in info button there's information how to pick user id and of course it's different from site to site

as for the "limit to a day", that's so far how stack exchange api that im using works, im not aware of any other api which could yield date ranges rather than single days
